# LoadLibraryEx cannot find DLL or its dependencies

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

I am currently writing a program which loads a DLL (`a.dll`), which relies on another DLL (`b.dll`).

When using the [`LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) function, loading `a.dll` succeeds; so long as `b.dll` is in the same directory as the executable (no matter where `a.dll` is located). However, for my purposes, `b.dll` cannot be in the same directory as the executable. As such, I resorted to [`LoadLibraryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa), which has a flags parameter to give more specific parameters on loading DLLs. However, none of them seem to do anything. No matter what I have tried for the past few hours, all calls to `LoadLibraryEx` fail and return the error code [`126`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

```
HANDLE handle;

// this works if b.dll is in the same
// directory as the executable file
handle = LoadLibrary("a.dll");
FreeLibrary(handle);

// this also works, since using a value
// of zero for the flags makes it behave
// the same as LoadLibrary
handle = LoadLibraryEx("a.dll", NULL, 0);
FreeLibrary(handle);

// this does not work, even if b.dll is
// in the same directory as the executable
// file
handle = LoadLibraryEx("a.dll", NULL,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR);

// this does not work, even if b.dll is
// in the same directory as a.dll
handle = LoadLibraryEx("a.dll", NULL,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);

// this does not work, even if b.dll is
// in one of the directores specified by
// a sucessful call to AddDllDirectory
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie =
    AddDllDirectory(L"C:\\Fully\\Qualified\\Path");
handle = LoadLibraryEx("a.dll", NULL,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
RemoveDllDirectory(cookie);
```

Comment: Where is a.dll located in all trials?

Comment: The flags do not affect loading b.dll. a.dll should care if it. Are you aware of that the flags can be combined?

Comment: Yes, I am aware the flags can be combined. I have tried combining flags together and that doesn't seem to do anything either. I also tried using LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS, which is a combination of other flags, and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Furthermore, a.dll does not load b.dll using LoadLibrary. It is linked to b.dll at compile time, which it then loads at runtime (i.e., when the executable loads a.dll with LoadLibrary).

Comment: Try sysinternals process monitor to investigate a.dll and b.dll file open attempts and search paths https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `LoadLibraryEx` locates DLLs also applies to the DLL being loaded, not just its dependencies (this should have been obvious to me in hindsight, but that's where coding until 1:30AM gets you). If we have the following file structure, for example:

```
C:/
├─ Program Files/
│  ├─ My Program/
│  │  ├─ addons/
│  │  │  ├─ a.dll
│  │  ├─ depend/
│  │  │  ├─ b.dll
│  │  ├─ program.exe
```

And `program.exe` runs the following:

```
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie =
    AddDllDirectory(L"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\depend");
HANDLE handle = LoadLibraryEx("addons\\a.dll", NULL,
    LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
```

Windows will attempt to open `a.dll` at `C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\depend\\addons\\a.dll`, which fails, since that file does not exist. In this situation, this can be fixed in one of two ways.

1. By using an absolute path instead of a relative one.

```
// Since an absolute path is used, Windows does not need to search
// for a.dll (and thus, successfully opens it). Afterwards, it will
// search for, and successfully find, b.dll in the previously given
// depend folder.
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE cookie =
    AddDllDirectory(L"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\depend");
HANDLE handle =
    LoadLibraryEx("C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\addons\\a.dll",
    NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);

FreeLibrary(handle);
RemoveDllDirectory(cookie);
```

2. Or, by adding an an additional DLL directory (in this case, `C:\\Program Files\\My Program`).

```
// Here, since the program folder has also been added as a
// directory to search through, a.dll will be successfully
// found in the addons folder.
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE programCookie =
    AddDllDirectory(L"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\");
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE dependCookie =
    AddDllDirectory(L"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\depend");
HANDLE handle =
    LoadLibraryEx("addons\\a.dll",
    NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);

FreeLibrary(handle);
RemoveDllDirectory(programCookie);
RemoveDllDirectory(dependCookie);
```

Furthermore, **make sure to use wide character strings (e.g., `L"path"`) when supplying paths to `AddDllDirectory`!** When I didn't use them, `LoadLibraryEx` would sometimes look in the wrong folder. For example, `C:\\Fully\\Qualified\\Path` would become something like `C:\\Fully\\重武器家伙\\Path` — at least according to Process Monitor. On that note, **make sure you always use the correct string encoding for whatever function you are calling.**

---

Special thanks to [@273K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6752050/273k) for mentioning the [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to me in the comments. Both it and the [Dynamic-Link Library Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-security) article from Microsoft were instrumental in solving this issue.

Comment: There is also [SetDefaultDllDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories). According to [Searching for DLLs and Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa#searching-for-dlls-and-dependencies), *it can use a process-specific search path established with the **SetDefaultDllDirectories** and **AddDllDirectory** functions*. You need to **establish** the process-specific search path.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me! However, according to the function article: "This search path is used when LoadLibraryEx is called with no LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH flags." As such, I'm not sure what you mean by "establishing" the search path. If I didn't want to change the default behavior of LoadLibraryEx, wouldn't calling SetDefaultDllDirectories be unnecessary?

Comment: Have you checked the search path of *LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR* and *LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR*?

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how this is relevant to the answer. The problem, as stated in the answer, was that I was not accounting for the search path of the DLL being loaded (I incorrectly assumed it only applied to the dependencies of the DLL). The given example solutions use LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS since it is the most convenient.

Comment: Does it mean the path of *LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR* or the path of *LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR* cannot find `a.dll`?

Comment: That depends on the program's installation directory and the location of `a.dll`. If `b.dll` is in the same folder as `a.dll` when using LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR, then Windows will successfully find `b.dll` (assuming `a.dll` was found first). If `b.dll` is in the same location as the program's installation directory when using LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR, then Windows will also find it (even if it is not in the same directory as `a.dll`).

Comment: So, the point I want to highlight is **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR** works for the loaded DLL and its dependencies while **LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR** works only for the loaded DLL's dependencies, The *lpFileName* parameter must specify a fully qualified path.